# В каком числе правильнее поставить глаголы?

Tags: согласование

1. Всё больше игрушек имеют(ет) неприятный вид.
2. В наше время всё больше подростков смотрят(ит) фильмы ужасов и читают(ет) книги о вампирах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По правилу можно использовать **оба варианта согласования**, и тогда  сделаем выбор **для одуш. и неодуш.** предметов (пассивное и активное действие):

*Всё больше игрушек **имеет** неприятный вид.*

*В наше время всё больше подростков **смотрят** фильмы ужасов и читают книги о вампирах.*

**[Правило Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)** **§184.**

10. При обозначении **приблизительного количества** (путем постановки числительного впереди существительного или путем вставки слов **около, свыше, больше, меньше и т.п.**) сказуемое может стоять как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа (второй способ согласования **все чаще** встречается в наше время), например:

а) Оттуда поднялось десятка два человек (А.Н. Толстой); Под навесиком помещалось не больше четырех ребят... (Макаренко); За бугром лежало с десяток возчиков (Фурманов); Работало двадцать с лишним человек (Н. Островский);

б) Человек пять стали мыться в горном, холодном ручье (Горький); Не менее двадцати дам... сидели на зеленых скамейках и неотрывно глядели в сторону бухты (Сергеев-Ценский); Десятка два старых изб разместились по обеим сторонам пыльной улицы (Г. Гулиа).

**Ср. в периодической печати:** От двух до трех миллионов человек посещают Московский зоопарк ежегодно; Свыше 70 театров страны показали в эти дни чеховские спектакли; На «Грузии» совершили увлекательное путешествие более 750 туристов, Подписку на газеты и журналы принимают в Москве свыше 200 почтовых отделений; В результате наводнения более 100 тысяч человек терпят бедствие.